# Non trivial example of free action on Half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I'm learning Riemann surfaces with Donaldson' Riemann surfaces.

In Donaldson, he proved that if $X$ is Riemannian surfaces and $\Gamma$ is subgroup of group of holomorphic automorphism of $X$(that is, $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$) acts freely on $X$.

I want to find concrete non trivial example of $\Gamma$ but didn't.

For example let $\Gamma = \bigg\langle\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 &1\end{pmatrix}\bigg\rangle$, 
how I know whether this acts freely or not?

-

In previous example now I see this acts freely since 2+1>2. Just I didn't catch it. But It's too hard to visualize, so is there any 'nice' example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very straightforward example is the group generated by $T=\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}$.
This is the map $z\mapsto z+1$, and so has no fixed points. A disc $D$
with Euclidean diameter $<1$ is mapped by the powers of $T$ into a sequence
$(T^n(D))_{n=-\infty}^\infty$
of disjoint discs, which makes it clear that the action is free.

Comment: Wow, why I couldn't see this. Thank you.